# Unity3D hi res image of Canvas

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas in Unity3D with some Images and Text. I need to be able to turn that canvas into a picture of a set resolution, no matter what resolution the mobile app is running on.

I could do it by creating a Texture2D of the desired picture resolution and use get set pixels of the Images in that canvas, but this does not work for the text. How could I get the font as well?

Another thing would be to use a camera to take a picture of the canvas, but this is reliant on the Screen resolution. Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

UI has an option to automatically adjust the range size by assigning a minimum and a maximum at the source.

But perhaps you are interested in investigating this UIAutoLayout.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html
UI-Text , Paragraph, Best Fit. Assign Min Size and Max Size.

As each picture that you want to assign the maximum resolution that has the texture or you want most. Assigning for devices and platforms you will deploy.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Beware the automatic adjustment, misconfiguration causes loss of quality images and text fonts, especially with the automatic rescaling.

Hope this can help you.